# System.LimitException: Too many Email Invocations: 11 - Line: 63, Column: 1

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage

Could Not find proper solution for this Fatal Error. I have to send single single mail project wise.

```apex
global class CollectionDefaulterEmail2 implements Schedulable {
   global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx){
      Map<String,Billing_Payment__c> billMap =  New Map<String,Billing_Payment__c>();
      List<String> ProjectNameList = new List<String>();
      List<String> LocationList = new List<String>();
      List<String> OperatingRegionList = new List<String>();
      List<String> tatList = new List<String>();
      string tatmembers = 'abc@help.com';
      List<Billing_Payment__c> bill= [SELECT Id,Billing_Name__c,Project_Name__c,Payment_Received_Date__c,Project_Name__r.Name,Operating_Region__c,Invoice_Total__c, Overdue_Days__c FROM Billing_Payment__c WHERE Overdue_Days__c > 10 AND Payment_Received_Date__c=NULL];
      for(Billing_Payment__c b:bill){
         billMap.put(b.Id,b);
         ProjectNameList.add(b.Project_Name__c);
         LocationList.add(b.Operating_Region__c);
         OperatingRegionList.add(b.Operating_Region__c);
      }
      List<Internal_Kickoff__c> kickoff = [SELECT Id, Name, ProjectName__c,SPOC__c, SPOC__r.Email, ProjectName__r.LL_Location__c FROM Internal_Kickoff__c WHERE ProjectName__c in: ProjectNameList AND ProjectName__r.LL_Location__c=: LocationList];
      List<User> uList = [SELECT Id, User.Name, Email, Role__c, UserRole.Name, Profile.Name, Region__c FROM User WHERE Role__c IN ('RH Pune', 'RH Mumbai', 'RH Hyderabad', 'RH Bangalore 2') AND Region__c in: OperatingRegionList];
      List<Billing_Payment__c> BillingPaymentList =[SELECT Id,Payment_Received_Date__c,Billing_Name__c,Invoice_Date__c,Invoice_No__c,Type_of_Invoice__c,PO_No__c,Basic_Value_Formula__c,Tax_Total_Formula__c,Invoice_Total__c,No_of_days_Due__c, Project_Name__r.Name,Project_Name__c, Overdue_Days__c, Operating_Region__c FROM Billing_Payment__c WHERE Project_Name__c in: ProjectNameList AND Operating_Region__c= 'Mumbai' AND  Overdue_Days__c > 10 AND Payment_Received_Date__c=NULL ];
      List<Billing_Payment__c> BillingPaymentList2=[SELECT Id,Payment_Received_Date__c,Billing_Name__c,Invoice_Date__c,Invoice_No__c,Type_of_Invoice__c,PO_No__c,Basic_Value_Formula__c,Tax_Total_Formula__c,Invoice_Total__c,No_of_days_Due__c, Project_Name__r.Name,Project_Name__c, Overdue_Days__c, Operating_Region__c FROM Billing_Payment__c WHERE Project_Name__c in: ProjectNameList AND Operating_Region__c= 'Pune'  AND Overdue_Days__c > 10  AND Payment_Received_Date__c=NULL];
      List<Billing_Payment__c> BillingPaymentList3=[SELECT Id,Payment_Received_Date__c,Billing_Name__c,Invoice_Date__c,Invoice_No__c,Type_of_Invoice__c,PO_No__c,Basic_Value_Formula__c,Tax_Total_Formula__c,Invoice_Total__c,No_of_days_Due__c, Project_Name__r.Name,Project_Name__c, Overdue_Days__c, Operating_Region__c FROM Billing_Payment__c WHERE Project_Name__c in: ProjectNameList AND Operating_Region__c= 'Bangalore'  AND Overdue_Days__c > 10  AND Payment_Received_Date__c=NULL];
      List<Billing_Payment__c> BillingPaymentList4=[SELECT Id,Payment_Received_Date__c,Billing_Name__c,Invoice_Date__c,Invoice_No__c,Type_of_Invoice__c,PO_No__c,Basic_Value_Formula__c,Tax_Total_Formula__c,Invoice_Total__c,No_of_days_Due__c, Project_Name__r.Name,Project_Name__c, Overdue_Days__c, Operating_Region__c FROM Billing_Payment__c WHERE Project_Name__c in: ProjectNameList AND Operating_Region__c ='Hyderabad'  AND Overdue_Days__c > 10  AND Payment_Received_Date__c=NULL];
      for ( Billing_Payment__c Billandpayment : bill ){
         for (Internal_Kickoff__c kick: kickoff){
            if (Billandpayment.Project_Name__c == kick.ProjectName__c){
               if (Billandpayment.Overdue_Days__c > 10 && Billandpayment.Payment_Received_Date__c==null && Billandpayment.Project_Name__c == kick.ProjectName__c){
                  if (Billandpayment.Operating_Region__c == 'Mumbai'){
                     system.debug('Came in Mumbai');
                     string rhEmail;
                     for(User u :uList){
                        if(u.Role__c == 'RH Mumbai'){
                           rhEmail=u.Email+',billing@help.com';
                        }
                     }
                     String mailSubject = Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c + ' | '+Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name + ' | Mumbai Region | Billing and Payment Collection PAST OVERDUE';
                     String mailBody = '<p> Dear Sir/Madam,</p></br>';
                     String mailBody1 = '<p>The following bill payment is pending.Request to do the needful. </p></br>';
                     String mailBody2 = '<h4> Billing and Payment Defaulter </h4></br>';
                     mailBody = mailBody + mailBody1 + mailBody2 +'<table border=1><tr><th>Billing Name</th><th>Project Name</th><th>Operating Region</th><th>Bill Date</th><th>Bill No.</th><th>Type</th><th>PO No.</th><th>Net Amount</th><th>Taxes</th><th>Total Bill Amount</th><th>No. of Days due</th><th>Overdue Days</th></tr>';
                     for (Billing_Payment__c BP: BillingPaymentList){
                        if(BP.Project_Name__r.Name == Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name  && Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c == BP.Billing_Name__c){
                           if (kick.SPOC__r.Email != null){
                              tatmembers = tatmembers+','+ kick.SPOC__r.Email;
                              tatList.add(kick.SPOC__r.Email);
                           }
                           tatList.add('abc@help.com');
                           mailBody = mailBody + '<tr>';
                           mailBody = mailBody + '<td>' + BP.Billing_Name__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Project_Name__r.Name + '</td><td>' + BP.Operating_Region__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Date__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_No__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.Type_of_Invoice__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.PO_No__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Basic_Value_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Tax_Total_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Total__c + '</td><td>' + BP.No_of_days_Due__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Overdue_Days__c + '</td>';
                           mailBody = mailBody + '</tr>';   
                        }
                     }
                     mailBody = mailBody + '</table>';
                            EmailController.sendEmail( 'xyz@help.com' ,'null', 'null' , 'xyz@help.com', mailSubject, mailBody+' | TAT: '+tatmembers + ' | RH: ' + rhEmail);
                     System.debug('tatList Mumbai==>'+tatList);
                     tatmembers =''abc@help.com';
                     tatList.clear();
                  }
                  else if (Billandpayment.Operating_Region__c == 'Pune'){
                     system.debug('Came in pune');
                     string rhEmail;
                     for(User u :uList){
                        if(u.Role__c == 'RH Pune'){
                           rhEmail=u.Email+',pune.billing@help.com';
                        }
                     }
                     String mailSubject = Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c + ' | '+Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name + ' | Pune Region | Billing and Payment Collection PAST OVERDUE';
                     String mailBody = '<p> Dear Sir/Madam,</p></br>';
                     String mailBody1 = '<p>The following bill payment is pending.Request to do the needful. </p></br>';
                     String mailBody2 = '<h4> Billing and Payment Defaulter </h4></br>';
                     mailBody = mailBody + mailBody1 + mailBody2 +'<table border=1><tr><th>Billing Name</th><th>Project Name</th><th>Operating Region</th><th>Bill Date</th><th>Bill No.</th><th>Type</th><th>PO No.</th><th>Net Amount</th><th>Taxes</th><th>Total Bill Amount</th><th>No. of Days due</th><th>Overdue Days</th></tr>';
                     for (Billing_Payment__c BP: BillingPaymentList2){
                        if(BP.Project_Name__r.Name == Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name  && Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c == BP.Billing_Name__c ){
                           if (kick.SPOC__r.Email != null){
                              tatmembers = tatmembers+','+ kick.SPOC__r.Email;
                              tatList.add(kick.SPOC__r.Email);
                           }
                           tatList.add('abc@help.com');
                           mailBody = mailBody + '<tr>';
                           mailBody = mailBody + '<td>' + BP.Billing_Name__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.Project_Name__r.Name + '</td><td>' + BP.Operating_Region__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Date__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_No__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.Type_of_Invoice__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.PO_No__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Basic_Value_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Tax_Total_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Total__c + '</td><td>' + BP.No_of_days_Due__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Overdue_Days__c + '</td>';
                           mailBody = mailBody + '</tr>';
                        }
                     }
                     mailBody = mailBody + '</table>';
                     EmailController.sendEmail( 'abc@help.com' ,'null', 'null' , 'abc@help.com', mailSubject, mailBody+' | TAT: '+tatmembers + ' | RH: ' + rhEmail);
                     System.debug('tatList pune==>'+tatList);
                     tatmembers = 'abc@help.com';
                     tatList.clear();
                  }
                  else if (Billandpayment.Operating_Region__c == 'Bangalore'){
                     string rhEmail;
                     for(User u :uList){
                        if(u.Role__c == 'RH Bangalore 2'){
                           rhEmail=u.Email+',blr.billing@help.com';
                        }
                     }
                     String mailSubject = Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c + ' | '+Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name + ' | Bangalore Region | Billing and Payment Collection PAST OVERDUE';
                     String mailBody = '<p> Dear Sir/Madam,</p></br>';
                     String mailBody1 = '<p>The following bill payment is pending.Request to do the needful. </p></br>';
                     String mailBody2 = '<h4> Billing and Payment Defaulter </h4></br>';
                     mailBody = mailBody + mailBody1 + mailBody2 +'<table border=1><tr><th>Billing Name</th><th>Project Name</th><th>Operating Region</th><th>Bill Date</th><th>Bill No.</th><th>Type</th><th>PO No.</th><th>Net Amount</th><th>Taxes</th><th>Total Bill Amount</th><th>No. of Days due</th><th>Overdue Days</th></tr>';
                     for (Billing_Payment__c BP: BillingPaymentList3){
                        if(BP.Project_Name__r.Name == Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name  && Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c == BP.Billing_Name__c ){
                           if (kick.SPOC__r.Email != null){
                              tatmembers = tatmembers+','+ kick.SPOC__r.Email;
                              tatList.add(kick.SPOC__r.Email);
                           }
                           tatList.add('abc@help.com');
                           mailBody = mailBody + '<tr>';
                           mailBody = mailBody + '<td>' + BP.Billing_Name__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Project_Name__r.Name + '</td><td>' + BP.Operating_Region__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Date__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_No__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.Type_of_Invoice__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.PO_No__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Basic_Value_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Tax_Total_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Total__c + '</td><td>' + BP.No_of_days_Due__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Overdue_Days__c + '</td>';
                           mailBody = mailBody + '</tr>';
                        }
                     }
                     mailBody = mailBody + '</table>';
                     EmailController.sendEmail( 'abc@help.com' ,'null', 'null' , 'abc@help.com', mailSubject, mailBody+' | TAT: '+tatmembers + ' | RH: ' + rhEmail);
                     System.debug('tatList Banglore==>'+tatList);
                     tatList.clear();
                     tatmembers = 'abc@help.com';
                  }
                  else if (Billandpayment.Operating_Region__c == 'Hyderabad'){
                     string rhEmail;
                     for(User u :uList){
                        if(u.Role__c == 'RH Hyderabad'){
                           rhEmail=u.Email+',hyd.billing@help.com';
                        }
                     }
                     String mailSubject =Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c + ' | '+Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name + ' | Hyderabad Region | Billing and Payment Collection PAST OVERDUE';
                     String mailBody = '<p>Dear Sir/Madam,</p></br>';
                     String mailBody1 = '<p>The following bill payment is pending.Request to do the needful. </p></br>';
                     String mailBody2 = '<h4> Billing and Payment Defaulter </h4></br>';
                     mailBody = mailBody + mailBody1 + mailBody2 +'<table border=1><tr><th>Billing Name</th><th>Project Name</th><th>Operating Region</th><th>Bill Date</th><th>Bill No.</th><th>Type</th><th>PO No.</th><th>Net Amount</th><th>Taxes</th><th>Total Bill Amount</th><th>No. of Days due</th><th>Overdue Days</th></tr>';
                     for (Billing_Payment__c BP: BillingPaymentList4){
                        if(BP.Project_Name__r.Name == Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name  && Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c == BP.Billing_Name__c ){
                           if (kick.SPOC__r.Email != null){
                              tatmembers = tatmembers+','+ kick.SPOC__r.Email;
                              tatList.add(kick.SPOC__r.Email);
                           }
                           tatList.add('abc@help.com');
                           mailBody = mailBody + '<tr>';
                           mailBody = mailBody + '<td>' + BP.Billing_Name__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Project_Name__r.Name + '</td><td>' + BP.Operating_Region__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Date__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_No__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.Type_of_Invoice__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.PO_No__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Basic_Value_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Tax_Total_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Total__c + '</td><td>' + BP.No_of_days_Due__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Overdue_Days__c + '</td>';
                           mailBody = mailBody + '</tr>';
                        }
                     }
                     mailBody = mailBody + '</table>';
                     EmailController.sendEmail( 'abc@help.com' ,'null', 'null' , 'abc@help.com', mailSubject, mailBody+' | TAT: '+tatmembers + ' | RH: ' + rhEmail);
                     System.debug('tatList hydreabad==>'+tatList);
                     tatmembers = 'abc@help.com';
                     tatList.clear();
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
      tatmembers = 'abc@help.com';
   }
}
```

Email controller Code

```apex
public class EmailController {
   public static String sendEmail(String toAddresses, String ccAddresses, String bccAddresses, String replytoAddresses, String msgSubject, String msgBody){
      Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(2);
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
      if(toAddresses != 'null'){
         String[] toAdd = toAddresses.split(',');
         mail.setToAddresses(toAdd); 
      }
      if(ccAddresses != 'null'){
         String[] ccAdd = ccAddresses.split(',');
         mail.setCcAddresses(ccAdd); 
      }
      if(bccAddresses != 'null'){
         String[] bccAdd = bccAddresses.split(',');
         mail.setBccAddresses(bccAdd); 
      }
      mail.setReplyTo(replytoAddresses);
      mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce');
      mail.setSubject(msgSubject);
      mail.setBccSender(false);
      mail.setUseSignature(false);
      mail.setHtmlBody(msgBody+msgSignature);
      Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
      return 'Message Send';
   }

   public static String sendEmailWithAttachment(String toAddresses, String ccAddresses, String bccAddresses, String replytoAddresses, String msgSubject, String msgBody, String msgUsrSignature, List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attachments){
      Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(2);
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
      if(toAddresses != 'null'){
         String[] toAdd = toAddresses.split(',');
         mail.setToAddresses(toAdd); 
      }
      if(ccAddresses != 'null'){
         String[] ccAdd = ccAddresses.split(',');
         mail.setCcAddresses(ccAdd); 
      }
      if(bccAddresses != 'null'){
         String[] bccAdd = bccAddresses.split(',');
         mail.setBccAddresses(bccAdd); 
      }
      mail.setReplyTo(replytoAddresses);
      mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce');
      mail.setSubject(msgSubject);
      mail.setBccSender(false);
      mail.setUseSignature(false);
      mail.setHtmlBody(msgBody+msgSignature);
      mail.setFileAttachments(attachments);
      Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
      return 'Message Send';
   }
}
```

---

##### UPDATED CODE

```apex
global class CollectionDefaulterEmail2 implements System.Queueable {
   @testVisible
   private static Boolean doChainJob = true;
   global void execute(QueueableContext content) {
      Map<String,Billing_Payment__c> billMap =  New Map<String,Billing_Payment__c>();
      List<String> ProjectNameList = new List<String>();
      List<String> LocationList = new List<String>();
      List<String> OperatingRegionList = new List<String>();
      List<String> tatList = new List<String>();
      string tatmembers = 'ashima.agarwal@listenlights.com.Invalid';
      List<Billing_Payment__c> bill= [SELECT Id,Billing_Name__c,Project_Name__c,Payment_Received_Date__c,Project_Name__r.Name,Operating_Region__c,Invoice_Total__c, Overdue_Days__c FROM Billing_Payment__c WHERE Overdue_Days__c > 10 AND Payment_Received_Date__c=NULL];
      for(Billing_Payment__c b:bill){
         billMap.put(b.Id,b);
         ProjectNameList.add(b.Project_Name__c);
         LocationList.add(b.Operating_Region__c);
         OperatingRegionList.add(b.Operating_Region__c);        
      }
      List<User> uList;
      if(Test.isRunningTest()){
         uList = [SELECT Id, User.Name, Email, Role__c, UserRole.Name, Profile.Name, Region__c FROM User WHERE Role__c IN ('RH Pune', 'RH Mumbai', 'RH Hyderabad', 'RH Bangalore')];
      }else{
         uList = [SELECT Id, User.Name, Email, Role__c, UserRole.Name, Profile.Name, Region__c FROM User WHERE Role__c IN ('RH Pune', 'RH Mumbai', 'RH Hyderabad', 'RH Bangalore') AND Region__c in: OperatingRegionList];             
      }
      List<Billing_Payment__c> BillingPaymentList =[SELECT Id,Payment_Received_Date__c,Billing_Name__c,Invoice_Date__c,Invoice_No__c,Type_of_Invoice__c,PO_No__c,Basic_Value_Formula__c,Tax_Total_Formula__c,Invoice_Total__c,No_of_days_Due__c, Project_Name__r.Name,Project_Name__c, Overdue_Days__c, Operating_Region__c FROM Billing_Payment__c WHERE Project_Name__c in: ProjectNameList AND Operating_Region__c IN ('Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Bangalore','Hyderabad')  AND  Overdue_Days__c > 10 AND Payment_Received_Date__c=NULL ];
      for ( Billing_Payment__c Billandpayment : bill ){
         if (Billandpayment.Overdue_Days__c > 10 && Billandpayment.Payment_Received_Date__c==null){
            //Operating Region = Mumbai
            if (Billandpayment.Operating_Region__c == 'Mumbai' ){
               system.debug('Came in Mumbai');
               string rhEmail;
               for(User u :uList){
                  if(u.Role__c == 'RH Mumbai'){
                     rhEmail=u.Email+',billing@xys.com';
                  }
               } 
               String mailSubject = Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c + ' | '+Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name + ' | Mumbai Region | Billing and Payment Collection PAST OVERDUE';
               String mailBody = '<p> Dear Sir/Madam,</p></br>';
               String mailBody1 = '<p>The following bill payment is pending.Request to do the needful. </p></br>';
               String mailBody2 = '<h4> Billing and Payment Defaulter </h4></br>';
               mailBody = mailBody + mailBody1 + mailBody2 +'<table border=1><tr><th>Billing Name</th><th>Project Name</th><th>Operating Region</th><th>Bill Date</th><th>Bill No.</th><th>Type</th><th>PO No.</th><th>Net Amount</th><th>Taxes</th><th>Total Bill Amount</th><th>No. of Days due</th><th>Overdue Days</th></tr>';
               for (Billing_Payment__c BP: BillingPaymentList){
                  if(BP.Operating_Region__c== 'Mumbai' && BP.Project_Name__r.Name == Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name  && Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c == BP.Billing_Name__c){
                     tatList.add('abc@gmail.com');
                     mailBody = mailBody + '<tr>';
                     mailBody = mailBody + '<td>' + BP.Billing_Name__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Project_Name__r.Name + '</td><td>' + BP.Operating_Region__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Date__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_No__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.Type_of_Invoice__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.PO_No__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Basic_Value_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Tax_Total_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Total__c + '</td><td>' + BP.No_of_days_Due__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Overdue_Days__c + '</td>';
                     mailBody = mailBody + '</tr>';   
                  }
               }
               mailBody = mailBody + '</table>';
               mailController.sendEmail('abc@gmail.com','null', 'null' , 'abc@gmail.com', mailSubject, mailBody+' | TAT: '+tatmembers + ' | RH: ' + rhEmail);
               System.debug('tatList Mumbai==>'+tatList);
               system.debug('rhEmail='+ rhEmail);
               tatmembers ='abc@gmail.com';
               tatList.clear();
            }  
            //Operating Region = Pune
            else if (Billandpayment.Operating_Region__c == 'Pune'){
               system.debug('Came in pune');
               string rhEmail;
               for(User u :uList){
                  if(u.Role__c == 'RH Pune'){
                     rhEmail=u.Email+',pune.billing@abx.com';
                  }
               } 
               String mailSubject = Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c + ' | '+Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name + ' | Pune Region | Billing and Payment Collection PAST OVERDUE';
               String mailBody = '<p> Dear Sir/Madam,</p></br>';
               String mailBody1 = '<p>The following bill payment is pending.Request to do the needful. </p></br>';
               String mailBody2 = '<h4> Billing and Payment Defaulter </h4></br>';
               mailBody = mailBody + mailBody1 + mailBody2 +'<table border=1><tr><th>Billing Name</th><th>Project Name</th><th>Operating Region</th><th>Bill Date</th><th>Bill No.</th><th>Type</th><th>PO No.</th><th>Net Amount</th><th>Taxes</th><th>Total Bill Amount</th><th>No. of Days due</th><th>Overdue Days</th></tr>';
               for (Billing_Payment__c BP: BillingPaymentList){
                  if(BP.Operating_Region__c== 'Pune' && BP.Project_Name__r.Name == Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name  && Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c == BP.Billing_Name__c ){
                     tatList.add('abc@gmail.com');
                     mailBody = mailBody + '<tr>';
                     mailBody = mailBody + '<td>' + BP.Billing_Name__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.Project_Name__r.Name + '</td><td>' + BP.Operating_Region__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Date__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_No__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.Type_of_Invoice__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.PO_No__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Basic_Value_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Tax_Total_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Total__c + '</td><td>' + BP.No_of_days_Due__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Overdue_Days__c + '</td>';
                     mailBody = mailBody + '</tr>';
                  }
               }
               mailBody = mailBody + '</table>';
               EmailController.sendEmail('abc@gmail.com' ,'null', 'null' , 'abc@gmail.com', mailSubject, mailBody+' | TAT: '+tatmembers + ' | RH: ' + rhEmail);
               System.debug('tatList pune==>'+tatList);
               system.debug('rhEmail='+ rhEmail);
               tatmembers = 'abc@gmail.com';
               tatList.clear();
            }
            //Operating Region = Bangalore
            else if (Billandpayment.Operating_Region__c == 'Bangalore'){
               string rhEmail;
               for(User u :uList){
                  if(u.Role__c == 'RH Bangalore'){
                     rhEmail=u.Email+',blr.billing@abc.com';
                  }
               }
               String mailSubject = Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c + ' | '+Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name + ' | Bangalore Region | Billing and Payment Collection PAST OVERDUE';
               String mailBody = '<p> Dear Sir/Madam,</p></br>';
               String mailBody1 = '<p>The following bill payment is pending.Request to do the needful. </p></br>';
               String mailBody2 = '<h4> Billing and Payment Defaulter </h4></br>';
               mailBody = mailBody + mailBody1 + mailBody2 +'<table border=1><tr><th>Billing Name</th><th>Project Name</th><th>Operating Region</th><th>Bill Date</th><th>Bill No.</th><th>Type</th><th>PO No.</th><th>Net Amount</th><th>Taxes</th><th>Total Bill Amount</th><th>No. of Days due</th><th>Overdue Days</th></tr>';
               for (Billing_Payment__c BP: BillingPaymentList){
                  if(BP.Operating_Region__c== 'Bangalore' && BP.Project_Name__r.Name == Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name  && Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c == BP.Billing_Name__c ){
                     tatList.add('abc@gmail.com');
                     mailBody = mailBody + '<tr>';
                     mailBody = mailBody + '<td>' + BP.Billing_Name__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Project_Name__r.Name + '</td><td>' + BP.Operating_Region__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Date__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_No__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.Type_of_Invoice__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.PO_No__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Basic_Value_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Tax_Total_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Total__c + '</td><td>' + BP.No_of_days_Due__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Overdue_Days__c + '</td>';
                     mailBody = mailBody + '</tr>';
                  }
               }
               mailBody = mailBody + '</table>';
               EmailController.sendEmail('abc@gmail.com' ,'null', 'null' , 'abc@gmail.com', mailSubject, mailBody+' | TAT: '+tatmembers + ' | RH: ' + rhEmail);
               System.debug('tatList Banglore==>'+tatList);
               system.debug('rhEmail='+ rhEmail);
               tatList.clear();
               tatmembers = 'abc@gmail.com';
            }
            //Operating Region = Hyderabad
            else if (Billandpayment.Operating_Region__c == 'Hyderabad'){
               string rhEmail;
               for(User u :uList){
                  if(u.Role__c == 'RH Hyderabad'){
                     rhEmail=u.Email+',hyd.billing@abc.com';
                  }
               }
               String mailSubject =Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c + ' | '+Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name + ' | Hyderabad Region | Billing and Payment Collection PAST OVERDUE';
               String mailBody = '<p>Dear Sir/Madam,</p></br>';
               String mailBody1 = '<p>The following bill payment is pending.Request to do the needful. </p></br>';
               String mailBody2 = '<h4> Billing and Payment Defaulter </h4></br>';
               mailBody = mailBody + mailBody1 + mailBody2 +'<table border=1><tr><th>Billing Name</th><th>Project Name</th><th>Operating Region</th><th>Bill Date</th><th>Bill No.</th><th>Type</th><th>PO No.</th><th>Net Amount</th><th>Taxes</th><th>Total Bill Amount</th><th>No. of Days due</th><th>Overdue Days</th></tr>';
               for (Billing_Payment__c BP: BillingPaymentList){
                  if(BP.Operating_Region__c== 'Hyderabad' && BP.Project_Name__r.Name == Billandpayment.Project_Name__r.Name  && Billandpayment.Billing_Name__c == BP.Billing_Name__c ){
                     tatList.add('abc@gmail.com');
                     mailBody = mailBody + '<tr>';
                     mailBody = mailBody + '<td>' + BP.Billing_Name__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Project_Name__r.Name + '</td><td>' + BP.Operating_Region__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Date__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_No__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.Type_of_Invoice__c + '</td><td>'+ BP.PO_No__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Basic_Value_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Tax_Total_Formula__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Invoice_Total__c + '</td><td>' + BP.No_of_days_Due__c + '</td><td>' + BP.Overdue_Days__c + '</td>';
                     mailBody = mailBody + '</tr>';
                  }
               }
               mailBody = mailBody + '</table>';
               EmailController.sendEmail('abc@gmail.com','null', 'null' , 'abc@gmail.com', mailSubject, mailBody+' | TAT: '+tatmembers + ' | RH: ' + rhEmail);
               System.debug('tatList hydreabad==>'+tatList);
               system.debug('rhEmail='+ rhEmail);
               tatmembers = 'abc@gmail.com';
               tatList.clear();
            }
            if(doChainJob){System.enqueueJob(new CollectionDefaulterEmail2());}
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `EmailController.sendEmail` is nested in one or more for loops resulting in more than 10 attempts of trying to send individual emails (limit is 10 per context). You should have your `sendEmail` functionality in a batched context with a batch size of 10 or less. see ['Too many API email invocations 11' error when sending emails via Apex](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000324660&type=1)

Comment: I have Email Controller. Pasting the code in answer. @TSmith

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add that information.

Comment: Having email controller code in a separate class does not remove the fact that, as TSmith pointed out, you are calling it from within a loop. You are just calling it from within a loop from a different location, not a different transaction.

Comment: @Moonpie: How can I do that in my code?

Comment: Please do not edit your original code in the question to update it. Instead, add it as an update. This is because it could confuse future readers and/or helpers when they read the question and any comments or answers. (I have already rolled back your edit and added it as an update at the bottom.)

Comment: @Moonpie: yes, thank you for that. But I am still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a number of issues/potential problems/inefficiencies in your code, but I do not have time to look for all of them - much less address them.  But I do want to point out a few things:

1. These lines...

   ```
   string rhEmail;
   for(User u :uList){
       if(u.Role__c == 'RH Mumbai'){
           rhEmail=u.Email+',billing@help.com';
       }
   }
   ```

   ...may not be doing what you want them to do.

   If you have more than one User in the list whose `Role__c` is "RH Mumbai", then the value in `rhEmail` gets overwritten so that only the last User's email address from the list of Users will be saved in the `rhEmail` variable.
2. You have four queries with the exact same SOQL except that they each look for a different `Operating_Region__c` value and build four different `BillingPaymentList`s. You could use `WHERE Operating_Region__c IN ('Pune', 'Mumbai'...)` to save them in one `BillingPaymentList` list, and remove three queries.
3. Related to that, later you have conditionals which check for `Operating_Region__c` values in a different object to determine which of the four lists to use. Instead, you should be able to use the one new `BillingPaymentList` list which contains records with all four `Operating_Region__c` values, change your conditionals, and remove a lot of repetitious code.
4. You have a LOT of redundancy in your code. It could be cleaned up and compacted a lot; but at the very least you could find all of the common code in each of your inner `if else` statements where you are building your email message and move that to a separate method. That method would take as parameter(s) the one or few things which are different in each section of your message-building code.
5. You need to learn to use [Maps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm).

---

**But to get to your original question**, as @TSmith stated in his comment, and as the Salesforce Help page he linked to explains, you should not make calls to `sendEmail()` (even if those calls are to another Class method that ultimately makes the `sendEmail()` calls) from within a loop.

Use the same process as you would for avoiding DML inside a loop: instantiate a List *outside* the loop(s), within the loop(s) add the emails you want to send to the List, then outside of the loop(s) you call `sendEmail()` on the List.

There are a few ways to approach it, and I would suggest doing the above items (plus some) first to improve your code as this could help make clearer which approach to take.  But with you current code you could try something like:

- Modify your email controller code to, instead of sending the email, return a `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` object.
- In every place where you currently have `EmailController.sendEmail( 'abc@help.com'...` that call would now return a `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` object that you would then add to a `List<`Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>`(that you instantiate outside of your first`for` loop).
- Somewhere call `Messaging.sendEmail()` using your List.  (I say somewhere because it would normally be a method to live inside your email controller, but it really depends on what other code improvements you do [if any] and what those are.)

Comment: As you have mention point 1.That is working totally fine as I have single person for single role.  In point 2: Yes as per your suggestion I have change that and called in single SOQL. I have also used System.Queueable instead of scheduar. But still facing the same issue

Comment: The new code I have uploaded,but can not figure out how to use Messaging.sendEmail() instead of Email Controller

Comment: I did not intend for you to necessarily try to address all of those items at once (and those are not really everything). For a number of reasons, it is usually best to try to fix only one issue at a time; then test/check it; then move on to try to fix another issue.

Comment: Are you able to change the Email Controller code, or are you only able to modify your main code and just call the Email Controller code as needed?

Comment: Actually your points was right and I realise that I am doing same work in 3-4 SOQL. Yes I can only make changes in my main code only